# How do I create an Ubuntu installation disk on Windows to install on my new computer?

Tags: system-installation

I do not want to install Ubuntu desktop to my windows computer, but I want to install on a new hard drive on a separate computer.  How do I create an install disk without messing with my current computer.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is:

- Download an ISO for Ubuntu from this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
- Then you want to burn that ISO to a disc or USB drive, for windows I'd use Rufus for USB burning: https://rufus.akeo.ie/ this will also format the usb drive for you.
- Make sure you checkmark the "Make Bootable" checkbox so that you can boot of the USB Drive.
- Insert the USB Drive into your other computer. Reboot it, and spam the F12 button to bring up the boot menu
- Select your USB drive to boot off of it.
- Follow this link for instructions on installing it on your other computer: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: I do not have a usb device can I create a boot CD?

Comment: You have to use a DVD as the Ubuntu iso is larger then a CD.